# Архитектура базы данных многопользовательского приложения

Tags: база-данных, архитектура, проектирование

Проектирую многопользовательское приложение (клиент-сервер-бд), в БД необходимо хранить финансовые операции (дата, вид, категория, фин.счет, сумма, метка, комментарий) в большом количестве в среднем 1000 записей на каждого пользователя (с последующем увеличением).

Если делать одной таблицей, то ее размер будет расти при работе пользователей в приложении (пользователей минимум 1000). Думаю это не совсем логично, так как скорость обработки запросов будет снижаться и будут требоваться большие ресурсы, чтобы все клиенты могли без проблем получать информацию с БД.

Нашел, что есть мультитенантная архитектура, насколько здесь правильно будет ее использовать либо есть что-либо подходящее?